# why the code in jquery doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

the url is as this: `http://example.com/download/`

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
if(pathname=='download/'){
$("#subnav-content div:first").hide();
$("#subnav-content div:second").show();
}
```

why the above code in jquery doesn't work? i want to when the url is http://example.com/download/. show the secong div.

ps**:does this check affect the site performance?**

Comment: put `alert(pathname);` after your `pathname` declaration to see what the actual `window.location.pathname` is.  This will help you debug it a lot quicker.

Comment: What's happening when you do this? Have you checked the value of pathname using a JavaScript debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the leading slash.

'/download/'

If you expect query string parameters you may try a regular expression to just match the download portion of the url:  the following matches /download/.

```
if (window.location.pathname.match(/^\/download\//i))
```

Regarding the jquery, there is no :second, you need to use [:eq(1)](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
if(pathname=='/download/'){
$("#subnav-content div:first").hide();
$("#subnav-content div:eq(1)").show();
}
```

**Response to comments**

I'm putting my comment here because the formatting is horrible in the comments.  The regular expression for matching download can be summed up as follows:

`/` - start of regular expression matching syntax
`^` - means start matching at the very start of the screen
`\/` - means match the literal string '/', which is a special character which must be escaped
`download` - match the literal string 'download'
`\/` - again means match the literal string '/'
`/` - end of the matching syntax
`i` - regular expression options, i means ignore case

It was not clear to me what your other note was asking for.

Comment: you're right. but the second div not show? why?  div:second is it roght?

Comment: does this check affect the site performance? i add this to my js file. the page load slowly

Comment: That is pretty basic stuff.  Your best bet is to profile the javascript and see if it is actually taking a long time.

Comment: $("#subnav-content div:first").hide().next().show();  will also accomplish the same thing.

Comment: benjynito, if i want to use a regular expression to just match that the second part in the url are all beginning of download.eg:http://example.com/download/... how to rite the matches?

Comment: @zhuanzhou - see updated answer with meaning of the regular expression.  I'm not exactly sure what your other comment is asking to match, if you could explain a little more I'd be happy to help.

Comment: benjynito,got it. many happy. you made me know a lot. I can't say thank you too much.

Answer (score 2):

Second is not a selector.  You want:

```
$("#subnav-content div:nth-child(2)").show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
$("#subnav-content div:eq(0)")
$("#subnav-content div:eq(1)")
```

Also, you need to bind the code to an Event that will get fired when the Document is ready(`load`, or `onDOMReady` where supported) otherwise the `div`s might not exist in memory yet.

> ps*:does this check affect the site performance?*

Every line of code has an effect on site performance. Not necessarily a visible one although.